# Two Subscript/Superscript questions

Tags: string-manipulation, expression-manipulation, subscript

In mathematica code, I have a table of quantities that involve subscripts and superscripts. I need to put short text titles in the first row of the table. Suppose I have index1="A", index2="B", and index3="C", where A, B, and C are undefined symbols. (Later I might change A, B, and C to different symbols like $\mu,\nu$, and $\gamma $.)

Question 1. I desire an output of $\Gamma_{BC}^A \dot{x}^B\dot{x}^C$. I want to use an expression using index1, index2, and index3. I have tried things like ToExpression["$\Gamma_{index2  index3}^{index1}\dot{x}^{index2} \dot{x}^{index3}$"].

Question 2. I desire an output of $\partial_B$ $g_{CA}$ + $\partial_C$ $g_{AB}$.   As above, I have tried many variations of $\partial_{index2}$ $g_{index3 index1}$ + $\partial_{index3}$ g$_{index1 index2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Style[Row[{Subsuperscript[\[CapitalGamma], #2 #3, #1], 
      Superscript[OverDot[x], #2], 
      Superscript[OverDot[x], #3]}] & @@ {A, B, C}
  , 20] // TraditionalForm
```

$\Gamma _{B C}^A\dot{x}^B\dot{x}^C$

---

```
Style[Row[{Subscript[\[Delta], #2], Subscript[g, #2 #3], " + ", 
      Subscript[\[Delta], #3], Subscript[g, #1 #2]}] & @@ {A, B, C}
  , 20] // TraditionalForm
```

$\delta _Bg_{B C}\text{ + }\delta _Cg_{A B}$

Comment: This is great!. Thank you. I learned that "Row" mimics an expression where I control the arrangement rather than being dependent on the natural expression ordering of characters. And, I learned the &@@ trick to get A, B, and C to print out rather than index1, index2, etc. I was able to simplify your first answer, bypassing the &@@ trick, and I eventually was able to use del instead of delta in the 2nd one. I'll try to post my actual equations eventually. I don't think I can post them in a comment. Should I post them in "Answer Your Question" even though you have answered it?

Comment: Thanks for the accept.  I am glad I was able to help. The question can be answered to the extent of the details provided in the OP. It is therefore recommended to provide a minimal example. If your solution is different from this one, the site policy encourages you to share it. Have a nice day.

Comment: On 2nd thought my answers are similar enough not to post. Thanks again.